# uib typeahead to be integrated with existing dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to integrate uib-typeahead directive into a dropdown. So when they start typing an auto complete should come, if they choose the drop- down instead it should show the list of Items from the drop-down

```
<div id="parentDiv ">
    <select class="form-control " ng-model="$ctrl.name" ng-change="$ctrl.selectName()" ng-options="person.name for person in $ctrl.people ">
       <option value=" "></option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control app-input" placeholder="Name"  ng-model="$ctrl.name" required>
</div>
```

This works, when I override the style to the input hover on top of drop down
But when I try to make the input as an uib-typeahead nothing works.
I want the input to be more like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control app-input" placeholder="Name"  ng-model="$ctrl.name" maxlength="50" ng-model="$ctrl.name" typeahead-on-select="$ctrl.selectItem($item)" uib-typeahead="differentName.Name for differentName in $ctrl.differnetNames" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-wait-ms="600" />
```

This implementation might not be the optimal one, but I'm out of ideas.
I just want the first option to be an input with type ahead.
I am also trying my hand at manually providing the options using ng-repeat, still working on it. So any alternative best practices are welcome as well.

Also, I know this requirement sounds crazy, but I'm just the messenger.

**Update**
Tried `ng-repeat` way, and the only solution I figured is using styles to place the text field on top of the select, and hiding it whenever they interact with select. I'm positive that this is not a good practice at all. Hoping for any alternative solutions.

Comment: how about [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)?

Comment: Would you mind being more specific?

Comment: Tried it. Didn't find what I'm looking for.